# How to convert to JSON Format Realtime Database Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I managed to get one data from Firebase Realtime Database. This time I want to turn it into JSON format and get two data at least. Below is the code

my Database Reference
`

```
DatabaseReference ref =
        FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref().child('UsersData/$userDataUID/test/int');
```

my code `

```
StreamBuilder(
              stream: ref.onValue,
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  debugPrint(snapshot.data?.snapshot.value.toString());   
                }
                return const CircularProgressIndicator();
              })),
```

my Firebase console
[image]

I believe I have to convert it into Maps? I have no idea how to begin with

Comment: you can get the map with `child('UsersData/$userDataUID/test')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with

```dart
DatabaseReference ref =
        FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref().child('UsersData/$userDataUID/test');
```

This will return a map with those fields.

And use on widget like

```dart
 if (snapshot.hasData) {
     final map =  snapshot.data?.snapshot.value as Map?;
     return Text("int: ${map?["int"]}  voltage: ${map?["voltage"]}"); }
```

Find more about [getting data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data)

Comment: I tried your method but it shows the error on map?["int"] that says 'The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'DatabaseEvent'.
Try defining the operator '[]'.'

Comment: try `snapshot.data as Map?;`

Comment: new error : type 'DatabaseEvent' is not a subtype of type 'Map<dynamic, dynamic>?' in type cast

Comment: what do you get by printing `snapshot.data`

Comment: oh it should be `snapshot.data?.snapshot.value as Map?` i think

Comment: try `snapshot.data?.snapshot.value as Map?`

Comment: it works now after I put  '''  snapshot.data?.snapshot.value as Map? '''. Thank you very much!

Comment: Glad to help, also try attached link, it will provide better way